# How to recreate the default form error but in a action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-development-server

I am creating a button that triggers an action called sell that, as it says, sell a user thing. But the user must have an amount greater than 0 (things), on the database ( User.amount > 0), to be able to sell anything. I know that the default form have some error messages when the user left some parts blank. (a red message appears and do not let the user continue to the next page). I'm trying to do something similar, not letting the user go to the sell page, and displaying a message. That is my SELL action:

```
 def sell
  team_id = 9
 find_the_specific_row = current_user.user_stocks.find_by team: team_id

 if find_the_specific_row.nil? or find_the_specific_row == 0

 else
      find_the_specific_row.update(:amount => find_the_specific_row.amount - 1)
      redirect_to portfolios_path
  end
 end
```

The blank space after the if is where the code must be. 
I tried reading at the errors documentation but didn't find anything related to a situation like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to recreate the validation message when working with models, you can use the `errors.add` method to achieve this. In your case something along the lines of:

```
find_the_specific_row.errors.add(:amount, :greater_than, count: 0)
```

might be what you are looking for. This adds an error to your `amount` field that displays the greater_than error message you have defined in your locale file's error section.

Then, assuming you have the view setup to display these error messages, you should be able to get the desired result similar to that when using forms.

Take a look [at working with validation errors here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors) and it should hopefully be able to help you and provide more information about what can be done when working with validation errors.

If you don't want to link the errors to a model, then you can use `flash`.
flash is a variable that saves in the session to be displayed in the view, so you could write something like:

```
flash[:alert] = "Amount must be greater than 0"
```

and you can access the flash in the views, if you are redirecting, flash is ok, if you are rendering a view, you will need to use `flash.now`.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can read more about that and use it more in the way I want it ? And what do you mean about the 'assuming you have the view setup to display these error messages'? It is about the notice field on the top of the view?

Comment: @RedManBrasil I have added a link to my answer that can hopefully help you a bit more. What I mean is, I guess the view is already set up to display a models errors messages, and if it is then this should be okay.

Comment: It returns the error _undefined method `errors` for nil:NilClass_

Comment: Because the class is supposed to be null taking into account that the statement to enter the first **if**, is be nil or 0. And at this case it is null. That's my problem, I just want to display an error, not to link it with an class or anything, and I din't find anything on the documentation about that.

Comment: I see, if you don't want to link the errors to a model, then you can just use flash, flash is a variable that saves in the session to be displayed in the view, so you could write something like: flash[:alert] = "Amount must be greater than 0" and you can access the flash in the views, but please take not that is you redirect, flash is ok, if you are rendering a view, you will need to use flash.now, I am on my mobile at the moment and not in a position to write a long answer but I suggest reading up about using flash in rails

Comment: Yes! I read about flash messages and similar things and now I am able to do what I want! If you edit you answer and comment here again I mark your as the best answer! Thankss

Comment: @RedManBrasil I am happy you are able to do what you wanted! I have edited my answer to include the information about using flash, I hope you can accept it